# how to see the layout boxes in a math formula?

Tags: boxes, layout

Let's try a standard calculus formula, here the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
\end{document}
```

Here is the result of the integral of rational function. Notice there is a polynomial and a fraction.

[image]

Is there a way to see an "annotated" version of this formula with the boxes.  Here is what I found on a [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/math) page using their program `opentype`.

[image]

What are all the rectangles for?  Is there any way to get a similar picture in LaTeX?

Answer (score 4):

Wiht LuaTeX it is as easy as adding `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\begin{document}
\[ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]