# Extracting spatial metadata about \hboxes, \vboxes, glyphs, glues, etc

Tags: luatex, boxes, lua, dvi, metadata

I have been using TeX for almost 10 years, but only very recently decided to learn more about what TeX really does under the hood. This is because I want to display LaTeX-rendered text and mathematics in a visualisation tool that I am writing in C++. I plan to remotely invoke LuaTex from my code and then read in the rendered text as images. However, in order to have fine-grain control over the animation of individual words (and maybe even characters), I need to extract the spatial metadata (reference point location, height, depth, width, horizontal/vertical glue width, etc.) of the hierarchy of `\hbox`s and `\vbox`s so that I can manipulate individual boxes as per the use-case requirements.

I read the first half of The TeX Book recently, and have now been reading through a number of Overleaf articles on the inner workings of TeX. [This](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Pandora%E2%80%99s_%5Chbox%3A_Using_LuaTeX_to_Lift_the_Lid_of_TeX_Boxes) one in particular mentions how Lua can extract the metadata and create a node graph of the hierarchy of `\hbox`s and `\vbox`s from the `\hlists` and `\vlist`. So this seems like a viable option to write a recursive Lua script to extract the necessary metadata (although I'm yet to figure out how to write a Lua script that does so, so any recommendations on open-source parser scripts would be much appreciated). The other option, based on a recommendation in [my previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647341/inferring-the-baseline-height-and-bounding-box-widths-of-characters-text-equatio?noredirect=1#comment1613302_647341), is to extract the data directly from the .dvi file.

Can anyone advise me on which of the above options is a more tractable solution for my use case? Also, any resources for learning more about the recommended solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe look at savepos module of zref package? (which, as the documentation tells, use some "new" primitive provided by pdftex over Knuth-TeX, I think)

Comment: se also lua-visual-debug https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521839/1090

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle!

Comment: Thanks @user202729. I'll have a look at zref :)

Comment: @user202729 This is the trio (`\pdfsavepos`, `\pdflastxpos`, `\pdflastypos`) for pdfTeX and XeTeX, (`\savepos`, `\lastxpos`, `\lastypos`) for LuaTeX.